# How can I stop a launchd service?

Tags: postgresql, launchd, launchctl

I have a launchd service with label `homebrew.mxcl.postgresql`:

```
$ launchctl list homebrew.mxcl.postgresql
{
    "LimitLoadToSessionType" = "Aqua";
    "StandardErrorPath" = "/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log";
    "Label" = "homebrew.mxcl.postgresql";
    "TimeOut" = 30;
    "OnDemand" = false;
    "LastExitStatus" = 0;
    "PID" = 5436;
    "Program" = "/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres";
    "ProgramArguments" = (
        "/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres";
        "-D";
        "/usr/local/var/postgres";
    );
};
```

I want to stop this service! However, the obvious `stop` command does not work. Instead it restarts the service with a new PID:

```
$ launchctl stop homebrew.mxcl.postgresql
$ launchctl list homebrew.mxcl.postgresql
{
    "LimitLoadToSessionType" = "Aqua";
    "StandardErrorPath" = "/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log";
    "Label" = "homebrew.mxcl.postgresql";
    "TimeOut" = 30;
    "OnDemand" = false;
    "LastExitStatus" = 0;
    "PID" = 5819;
    "Program" = "/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres";
    "ProgramArguments" = (
        "/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres";
        "-D";
        "/usr/local/var/postgres";
    );
};
```

How do I actually stop the service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stopped job will be restarted right away if it’s supposed to be started. Instead, you must unload the service:

```
launchctl unload homebrew.mxcl.postgresql
```

To permanently disable it, also specifiy the `-w` switch:

```
launchctl unload -w homebrew.mxcl.postgresql
```

For Homebrew, there’s also [homebrew-services](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services). To install it:

```
brew tap homebrew/services
```

Then you can start and stop services more easily:

```
brew services start postgresql
brew services stop postgresql
```